# Wordpress Child problem in admin

Tags: wp-admin, child-theme

I created a child theme of Twenty Sixteen. It shows ok on the visitors' side, i.e. http://favrodsculpture.com.
But in the admin, I can't upload images, can't log out etc... If I write a post, it does get saved but I get a blank page when I save.
What did I do wrong?
My child's functions.php file is pretty simple, all it does is this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent_style', get_template_directory_uri() .     '/style.css' );
}
?>
<!-- Add favrod fonts, i.e. PT Sans and Ubuntu -->
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'favrod_fonts' );
function favrod_fonts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'favrod-fonts',  favrod_fonts_url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=PT+Sans:400,700,700italic,400italic|Ubuntu:400,500'), array(), null ); 
}
?>
```

Must add that the site is in a subfolder.
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'favrod_fonts' );` should be `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'favrod_fonts' );`. Also, you should really indent your code, messy code hides bugs and it is hard to read

Comment: @maria-jo: Do not add "solved" to the question title; edit your question with the details, or add your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest that clear cache first. If it still doesn't work, check the permission of wp-content directory.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, it turned out that my comment in the code caused the issue.